# How to run build and clean command to Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, liferay

I am newbie to `Jenkins`, how can I run any build and clean command at `Jenkins`?
actually have to re-build a project that will deploy to server . How to run this command "clean leslie" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure project job and modify Build Triggers,
choose Build periodically and set the Schedule field.
Moreover the Goals and oprtions field has to be set "clean leslie"